# Detect fargate service was upscaled

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

There's a fargate service that's configured to create more instances when CPU usage stays high for some period of time.

What I'm trying to do is to detect if the specific instance of the docker container is actually a new "upscaled" one.

Here's an example workflow:

```
Step 1:
Instances:
- Main

Step 2:
Instances:
- Main
- Temporary (upscaled)
- Temporary (upscaled)
- Temporary (upscaled)
- Temporary (upscaled)

Step 3:
Instances:
- Main
```

Is there a way to check if current instance is the "main" one? Like, use an environment variable or something.

Comment: Fargate is a deployment target for ECS and EKS. Which one are you using? ECS does not have any concept of a "main" task. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The ECS one. I want my jobs to run only on 1 instance.

Comment: What type of jobs? Some sort of schedule cron job type of thing? You really need to look into ways to manage things like that in a distributed system before you turn on auto-scaling of your service.

Comment: Yeah, kinda like that. You can name them cron jobs

Comment: I suggest looking at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981358/distributed-computing-in-c-sharp

Comment: And in general, you really shouldn't try locking jobs to a single instance, as that instance could be the one ECS deletes once it is time to scale down. Instead you should be looking into ways to prevent a job from running on multiple instances, but allow any instance to run the job.

Answer (score 0):

An individual running instance has no way to detect that it was started due to a scaling event.

You could build something that maintains this information using [EventBridge events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html#ecs_task_events): create a Lambda that responds to the task start and stop events by adding or removing rows from a DynamoDB table. Each row should include a count of how many rows were in the table at the time it was added; the row with the value 0 is your base task, anything else is the result of scaling.

You can then look at [ECS task metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html) to get the current task's ID, and retrieve its row from the DynamoDB table.

To be honest, this is an enormous amount of work, for imo very little value. If you describe the *actual* problem that you're trying to solve, you'll probably get much better solutions.